# Showing a modal dialog during the Drag-and-Drop operation

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I need to show a modal dialog during the drag-and-drop operation, however, this naturally freezes the folder containing the dropped file unless the dialog box is closed. What's the best of implementing such a code?

What comes to my mind is to exploit a background worker to open the modal dialog on another thread, or open a modeless dialog instead and disable the main window contents. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You won't be able to open a form on a new thread.

Comment: If you open some dialog box/form and move mouse to click on a control (e.g. a "Ok" button), the drag-and-drop operation will be cancelled (not only temporarily freezed).

Comment: It is normal scenario where a modal dialog is need to be shown. to do so you will need to persist the dragged data and process after taking input from dialog. i can explain further after you share some code that what are you trying to dragdrop

Comment: @Graffito-- I tested this with no problems; I dropped a file from Windows Explorer on the main form, and then the main form opened a new form during handling the DragDrop event. There is a button on the new form, I clicked it, and it performed as usual. The only problem was that the Windows Explorer froze until I have closed the new form.

Comment: @Munwar--Doesn't the question clear enough? I am dropping a file from Windows Explorer onto the main form of my program. I then need to process some data while handling the dropped file, which requires the user to drop another file on the newly opened form. After the user closes the secondary form, the procedure can be accomplished. Now, the question is that how I can prevent the Windows Explorer from getting frozen so that the user can drop another file on the second form.